# Create a multi column array using for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

So as the question states, im trying to create an array using a for loop, this seems as though its a simple question, but i cant find the asnwer on SO or googling. Heres what im doing:

```
$twelve=array("user","day");

for($i=0; $i<$value; $i++)
{
    $total=$anarray[$i][value]; //get a value

    $twelve[$i]=($i,$total);  //insert values into array
}
```

this doesn't work, how should i go about getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that does work

in each loop simply do:

```
$twelve[$i]["user"]=$i;
$twelve[$i]["day"]=$total;
```

It would be nice if there is a way to do that in one line, but that is working.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `$twelve[$i] = array($i, $total);`

Also, on this line;

```
$total=$anarray[$i][value]; //get a value
```

Unless `value` is defined as a constant, I think you want to do `$anarray[$i][$value];`.
PHP might not recognize value as a set variable or a constant, therefore crashes and never sets `$twelve` to any value.

Answer (score 1):

You may end up in a never-ending loop if `$total=$anarray[$i][value];`  is an increasing value. Regardless of the loop, you'll want to do as the other answerer mentioned, namely:
`$twelve[$i] = array($i, $total);`

Comment: yeah i saw that, it was a typo, however, using the initial answer is not working and giving me a blank answer